# How to compare json elements and display data in multidimensional array if they match?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON object at my disposal looking like this :

```
{
      "Fields": [
    {
      "table": "catalogue",
      "field": "Histo_Qtite",
      "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "table": "catalogue",
      "field": "id_article",
      "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "table": "contact",
      "field": "contact_email",
      "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "table": "contact",
      "field": "contact_firestname",
      "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "table": "customer",
      "field": "activity_type",
      "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "table": "customer",
      "field": "adress",
      "type": "STRING"
    }
  ],
  "Tables": [
    {
      "entity": "CATALOGUE",
      "table": "catalogue"
    },
    {
      "entity": "CLIENT",
      "table": "customer"
    },
    {
      "entity": "CONTACT",
      "table": "contact"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to create a multidimensional array for every "Fields" objects base on the name of the table. To do so I experimented with javascript and it resulted in this code :

```
var objectPREFIX = "object_",
selectedObject = '',
objectArray = [],
objectImport = [],
OFImport = [],
TablesLength = jsonImport.Tables.length,
FieldsLength = jsonImport.Fields.length;

 for (i = 0; i < FieldsLength; i++) {

    selectedObject = objectPREFIX + jsonImport.Fields[i].table;

    OFImport[selectedObject] = {
        tableName : jsonImport.Fields[i].table,
        FieldName : jsonImport.Fields[i].field,
        fieldType : jsonImport.Fields[i].type
    }

    for (j = 0; j < TablesLength; j++) {

        if(OFImport[selectedObject].tableName == jsonImport.Tables[j].table) {

            objectImport.push(OFImport[selectedObject]);
            objectArray[selectedObject] = OFImport[selectedObject];
        }
    }
}

console.log(objectArray);
```

The problem as I understand it is that `OFImport[selectedObject]` contain every object iteration of "Fields" and only display the last object in the console.

I would like to know how to make a comparison condition between "Fields" and "Tables" to get each iteration in separate arrays.

Here is a [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/a2quksyv/1/) that demonstrates the issue (sorry if I have troubles articulating my explanation).

Comment: Since you use `OFImport` as object you should initialize it as object too: `OFImport = {}` (not `OFImport = []`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what your looking to do, which is have an array of tables, which has an array of fields, then I think you have your `for` loops backwards.

you need to loop your tables first, then add your fields like so:-

```js
jsonImport = {
  "Fields": [{
    "table": "catalogue",
    "field": "Histo_Qtite",
    "type": "STRING"
  }, {
    "table": "catalogue",
    "field": "id_article",
    "type": "STRING"
  }, {
    "table": "contact",
    "field": "contact_email",
    "type": "STRING"
  }, {
    "table": "contact",
    "field": "contact_firstname",
    "type": "STRING"
  }, {
    "table": "customer",
    "field": "activity_type",
    "type": "STRING"
  }, {
    "table": "customer",
    "field": "adress",
    "type": "STRING"
  }],
  "Tables": [{
    "entity": "CATALOGUE",
    "table": "catalogue"
  }, {
    "entity": "CLIENT",
    "table": "customer"
  }, {
    "entity": "CONTACT",
    "table": "contact"
  }]
}

var objectArray = [],
    objectPREFIX = "object_",
    selectedObject = '',
    TablesLength = jsonImport.Tables.length,
    FieldsLength = jsonImport.Fields.length;

for (i = 0; i < TablesLength; i++) {

  selectedObject = objectPREFIX + jsonImport.Tables[i].table;
  
  objectArray[selectedObject] = {
    table: jsonImport.Tables[i].table,
    entity: jsonImport.Tables[i].entity,
    Fields: []
  }

  for (j = 0; j < FieldsLength; j++) {

    if (jsonImport.Tables[i].table == jsonImport.Fields[j].table) {

      objectArray[selectedObject].Fields.push({
        "field": jsonImport.Fields[j].field,
        "type": jsonImport.Fields[j].type
      });
    }
  }
}

console.log(objectArray);
```

outputting:-

[image]

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: may I ask if it is possible to get the same outputting than my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2quksyv/1/) with this solution? I can't figure how to rename `objectArray` with `selectedObject` and move `field` and `type` one level up.

Comment: i've updated my answer to set the name. but why would you want to take `field` and `type` up a level? if they are outside of an array on a property on table then they would just overwrite each time.

Comment: That was my original problem, it would have helped me with the rest of my code. Anyway I appreciate your support and thank you once again for helping me.